# Run a specific command from a different path in linux

Tags: path, ctags

I am working at a remote terminal with no sudo privileges. I am facing an issue with `ctags` command.

The `ctags` command which is run is emacs one (The one which does not help in code navigation) is located in `/usr/local/bin` & the exuberant `ctag` is located in `/usr/bin` . The machine `~/.bashrc` cannot be edited as it might mess up access to other installed binaries.

Is there a way I can just redirect the `ctags` command alone without messing up the rest of the `PATH` settings ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the full path to the desired ctags.

Comment: You mean to say on the command line everytime ? like [user/home]$ /usr/bin/ctag ?